# Is it possible to have a java swing border only on the top side?

Tags: java, swing, border

I know how to create borders using `BorderFactory` but I don't see anything that lets me specify what sides I want the border on :S

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#createapi):

> The next picture shows some matte
> borders. When creating a matte border,
> you specify how many pixels it
> occupies at the top, left, bottom, and
> right of a component.

[image]

([Java docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html))

Answer (score 90):

You can use the [MatteBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/MatteBorder.html) to specify the dimensions of the border in each side. The constructor of `MatteBorder` is:

```
public MatteBorder(int top,
                   int left,
                   int bottom,
                   int right,
                   Color matteColor)
```

So if you want to have a border only on the bottom and right sides of your `JPanel`, you could write something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the MatteBorder to use bevel style rounding for the corners? I need to use the matte border to control the sides of the element that are rendered, but i'm stuck with square corners. ;-(

Comment: Plus 1 for actually providing code. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 6):

Matte and empty border allow you to specify the sizes on each side, which may be zero.

The `Border` interface itself is quite easy to implement yourself if you want a custom look. I guess there may be third party libraries available containing styles not included within the Java library.

Answer (score 2):

```
text_field.setBorder( new MatteBorder(2, 0, 0, 0, Color.black));
```

The values can be varied accordingly.