# Rounded Border on one side only java

Tags: java, swing, border

I need to create a rounded border on **one side** of a component only.

This code creates a rounded border:

```
  new LineBorder(Color.RED, 3, true)
```

I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174319/is-it-possible-to-have-a-java-swing-border-only-on-the-top-side) which shows you how to create a matte border that can be used on one side of a component only, however a matte border isn't rounded.

Is it possible to have a rounded border on one side only?

**Edit:**

I have tried using compound border like this:

```
    cell.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
        new LineBorder(borderColor, 3, true),
        BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 3, 0, 0, Color.black)));
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6):

You can override the method of LineBorder and draw all you need there
From sources of LineBorder

```
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        int i;

    /// PENDING(klobad) How/should do we support Roundtangles?
        g.setColor(lineColor);
        for(i = 0; i < thickness; i++)  {
        if(!roundedCorners)
                g.drawRect(x+i, y+i, width-i-i-1, height-i-i-1);
        else
SET CLIP HERE TO DRAW ONLY NECESSARY PART
                g.drawRoundRect(x+i, y+i, width-i-i-1, height-i-i-1, thickness, thickness);
        }
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }
```

Comment: Relacing `g.drawRoundRect(...)` doesn't seem trivial, IMO. But it's a start - you'd have to draw the round corners and the edges separately.

Comment: @Thomas Easier said than done :P It's beyond me to draw the rounded corners with arcs. I've been trying but didn't manage yet.

Comment: As I said, it's not trivial, meaning "not that easy" :)

Comment: @Thomas http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/Graphics.java.html I can't understand. Why is there the source code of EVERYTHING except drawRoundRect and fillRoundRect????!

Comment: @David `Graphics` is an abstract class, you need to find the concrete subclass that implements those methods. Try [SunGraphics2D](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java.html).

Comment: @David for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-custom-button-in-java/5755124#5755124, +1

Comment: @mKorbel Yes but that uses `.drawRoundRect` not `.drawArc` :( I can't use drawRoundRect because I need only one side of the border (not all four).

Comment: @David nothing against your person, but as in your last post I think that you don't see the forest for the trees :-), java.awt.Border has four sides by default, I saw around some threads with topic about how to extract/change/colored particular Border from possitions (NORTH/SOUTH/WEST/EAST) http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1530__AbstractBorder.htm and another...

Answer (score 3):

`LineBorder` only supports all corners rounded or not. A compound border (as the JavaDoc states) uses one border for the outside and one for the inside and thus does not distinguish between left/right or top/bottom.

I'm afraid you'd either have to write your own `Border` implementation or look for one that's already made by someone else (external library).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example on how to use `Graphics2D#clipRect()`.
This code just keep the two right rounded corners and has normal borders on the left. As mentioned above, you will have to use this code inside your custom `LineBorder`.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

g2d.clipRect(150, 10, 100, 100);
g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(100, 10, 80, 30, 15, 15));

g2d.setClip(null);
g2d.clipRect(100, 10, 50, 100);
g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 10, 80, 30));
```

Comment: That code doesn't draw a rounded border when I use it to override paintBorder. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final int TOP_LEFT = 1;
public static final int TOP_RIGHT = 2;
public static final int BOTTOM_LEFT = 4;
public static final int BOTTOM_RIGHT = 8;
public static final int ALL_CORNERS = TOP_LEFT + TOP_RIGHT + BOTTOM_LEFT + BOTTOM_RIGHT;

public static void drawRoundRect(Graphics g, Color fillColor, Color borderColor, int x, int y, int width, int height, int radius, int cornerMask)
{
    // // XXX Old code (without selectively disabled round corners):
    // if (fillColor != null)
    // {
    // og.setColor(fillColor);
    // og.fillRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, radius, radius);
    // }
    // if (borderColor != null && !borderColor.equals(fillColor))
    // {
    // og.setColor(borderColor);
    // og.drawRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, radius, radius);
    // }
    radius += radius % 2; // so we don't have to deal with rounding issues for odd numbers
    int radiusHalf = radius / 2;
    width--;
    height--;
    if (fillColor != null)
    {
        g.setColor(fillColor);
        // og.fillRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, radius, radius);
        if ((cornerMask & TOP_LEFT) > 0)
        {
            g.fillArc(x, y, radius, radius, 90, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.fillRect(x, y, radiusHalf, radiusHalf);
        }
        if ((cornerMask & TOP_RIGHT) > 0)
        {
            g.fillArc(x + width - radius, y, radius, radius, 0, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.fillRect(x + width - radiusHalf, y, radiusHalf, radiusHalf);
        }
        if ((cornerMask & BOTTOM_RIGHT) > 0)
        {
            g.fillArc(x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 270, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.fillRect(x + width - radiusHalf, y + height - radiusHalf, radiusHalf, radiusHalf);
        }
        if ((cornerMask & BOTTOM_LEFT) > 0)
        {
            g.fillArc(x, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 180, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.fillRect(x, y + height - radiusHalf, radiusHalf, radiusHalf);
        }

        g.fillRect(x + radiusHalf, y, width - radius, radiusHalf);
        g.fillRect(x + radiusHalf, y + height - radiusHalf, width - radius, radiusHalf);
        g.fillRect(x, y + radiusHalf, radiusHalf, height - radius);
        g.fillRect(x + width - radiusHalf, y + radiusHalf, radiusHalf, height - radius);
        g.fillRect(x + radiusHalf, y + radiusHalf, width - radius, height - radius);
    }
    if (borderColor != null && !borderColor.equals(fillColor))
    {
        g.setColor(borderColor);

        // XXX: there are problems with this when using semi-transparent colors + borderSize > 1
        // XXX: this could be changed to to use ONE draw action using drawShape with GeneralPath.curveTo()
        // XXX: this then could also be used to FILL the shape (see above)
        if ((cornerMask & TOP_LEFT) > 0)
        {
            g.drawArc(x, y, radius, radius, 90, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + radiusHalf, y);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + radiusHalf);
        }
        if ((cornerMask & TOP_RIGHT) > 0)
        {
            g.drawArc(x + width - radius, y, radius, radius, 0, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.drawLine(x + width - radiusHalf, y, x + width, y);
            g.drawLine(x + width, y, x + width, y + radiusHalf);
        }
        if ((cornerMask & BOTTOM_RIGHT) > 0)
        {
            g.drawArc(x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 270, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.drawLine(x + width - radiusHalf, y + height, x + width, y + height);
            g.drawLine(x + width, y + height - radiusHalf, x + width, y + height);
        }
        if ((cornerMask & BOTTOM_LEFT) > 0)
        {
            g.drawArc(x, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 180, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            g.drawLine(x, y + height, x + radiusHalf, y + height);
            g.drawLine(x, y + height - radiusHalf, x, y + height);
        }

        g.drawLine(x + radiusHalf, y, x + width - radiusHalf, y); // top
        g.drawLine(x + width, y + radiusHalf, x + width, y + height - radiusHalf); // right
        g.drawLine(x + radiusHalf, y + height, x + width - radiusHalf, y + height); // bottom
        g.drawLine(x, y + radiusHalf, x, y + height - radiusHalf); // left
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example,

`JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,30,1,1));`