# Java GUI | How to give JLabel only top border

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border, jlabel

I created a GUI and now I created a JLabel, from which I only want to see the **top** border.

How does it get done?

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel( "TEXT" );
    label.setBounds( 90, 350, 440, 20 );
    label.setBorder( LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174319/is-it-possible-to-have-a-java-swing-border-only-on-the-top-side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy

```
lable.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) so you become familiar with all the standard Borders.

Comment: @camickr thanks for the link. I already know about most of the features, but something is new for me :)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy, my comment was for the OP to read the tutorial and become familiar with Swing features. I like to include links to the tutorial so the OP can learn about all the Borders (as well as other Swing features) the next time they have a problem. This way instead of answering a single question, hopefully I give the OP a resource to use for future problems as well.